# The problems with "Showed"

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Is it right to say

" Fisher (1935) has showed that normality is guaranteed in case 1"

Or should it be

" Fisher (1935) has shown that normality is guaranteed in case 1" ?

Personally, I guess both are not wrong. But then, the first one is wrong according to many. Please help !!

Comment: I would always use 'shown'.

Comment: I wonder what Fisher would have considered normal! At least OP doesn't throw in _shewed_ and _shewn_.

Answer (score 1):

The [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/show_1) says that *showed* is *rare* as a past participle.

So it will look very strange to many people, who are likely to insist that "showed" is *showed* is just the past tense of *show*.

So, while "has showed" is not *wrong*, at least according to some sources, the fact that some other sources do not include *showed* as past participle and some others label it as *rare* should explain why many will *find* it wrong.

Comment: Or to put it differently: _has showed_ is wrong to the vast majority of people, but there are a small minority of speakers who would not consider it wrong. [Disclaimer: I do not know if it is commonly used in something like Indian English, for example, which would significantly skew the numbers. I’m basing my majority/minority on BrE, AmE, IrE, ScE, AuE, and NZE alone.)